# Custom error response for URISyntaxException in Spring Boot Webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactive

In my rest endpoint (annotation based) I need to send in the email-id as path variable (e.g. `user/{email}`). Happy path works fine for this endpoint, but when I send some special characters in the URL (e.g. `user/-$!*%(^$)@google.com`) it throws `URISyntaxException`.

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Malformed escape pair at index: http://localhost:8080/user/-$!*%(^$)@google.com
```

Exception is fine and status is 400: Bad Request, also fine. But I don't get any body for this exception (not sure if there should be one). Now what I want to achieve here is to send a custom exception message to client

```
public class Response extends DefaultErrorAttributes {

    private String method;
    private String requestUri;
    private String status;
    private String message;
    private String timestamp;
    private String errorCode;
    private String debugMessage;
}
```

I'm not able to find a way to achieve this.
I have tried making use of `@RestControllerAdvice`

```
@Order(-2)
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public ResponseEntity<Response> handleGenericException(final ServerHttpRequest request,
                                                final Exception exception) {

    return buildErrorResponse(request, exception, INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

- 

```
private ResponseEntity<Response> buildErrorResponse(final ServerHttpRequest request,
                                                    final Exception exception,
                                                    final HttpStatus status) {
    log.error(exception.getMessage());
    Response response = Response.builder()
            .method(request.getMethodValue())
            .requestUri(request.getURI().toString())
            .status(status.toString())
            .message(exception.getMessage())
            .timestamp(util.getCurrentTimeInUtc())
            .debugMessage(exception.toString())
            .build();

    return ResponseEntity.status(status).contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).body(response);
}
```

I have also tried extending the `DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler`

Basically followed this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-errors#global
Still not able to intercept this exception and provide a custom message.

Is it possible?? What do I need to add to make it possible.

Comment: `in my rest endpoint` if you read the official docs (which i strongly recommend you should have done before you ask here on SO) there is 2 different ways of declaring rest endpoints and both have different ways in the docs (if your read them) of achiving error handling. So which way are you using to declare your endpoints. Functional or annotational

Comment: @Toerktumlare: Oh yes I have gone through them. I'm using annotation based endpoint.

Comment: Why don't you just encode the URL correctly? Then the problem disappears.

Comment: @user207421, I want to block users from entering rubbish inputs. I could have controlled it through @Pattern(regex="") but it doesn't reach at that point and Spring internally throws the exception. Also my motive is to send a custom response for every such case.